# Show all combinations of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tibble

I have the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(automatic = c("organismo", "bolha", "organismo", 
"organismo", "cosc_multiplo", "cosc_multiplo", "coscinodiscus", 
"detritos", "mult_organismos", "multiplos", "organismo", "sombra", 
"detritos", "mult_organismos", "detritos", "mult_organismos", 
"detritos", "org_partes", "detritos", "organismo", "organismo", 
"detritos", "organismo", "organismo", "organismo", "bolha", "coral_falso", 
"coscinodiscus", "detritos", "LRaw", "multiplos", "organismo", 
"sombra"), validated = c("appendicularia", "bolha", "cnidaria", 
"copepodo", "cosc_multiplo", "coscinodiscus", "coscinodiscus", 
"coscinodiscus", "coscinodiscus", "coscinodiscus", "coscinodiscus", 
"coscinodiscus", "detritos", "detritos", "langanho", "mult_organismos", 
"multiplos", "org_partes", "organismo", "organismo", "palmeria", 
"pelotas_mix", "phyto", "phyto_cadeia", "phyto_espiral", "sombra", 
"sombra", "sombra", "sombra", "sombra", "sombra", "sombra", "sombra"
), N = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1229L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 57L, 
1569L, 1L, 87L, 31L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 75L, 2L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 25L, 536L, 25L, 30L, 562L, 3678L)), row.names = c(NA, -33L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would to shown all combinations in columns automatic and validated.
For example, I hadn't the combination: bolha (in the `automatic` column) with appendicularia (in the `validated` column). I would like to show this combination, and the all other's absents, with a value of 0 in column `N`.

Where are combinations it has to maintain their value in N column. Like bolha (in automatic column) with bolha (in validated column) has a value in `N` of 1, it does not have to change.

Thanks all

Comment: Are you sure you have values of 0 in column N? This returns an empty table `subset(df, N==0)`

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get all unique combinations and maintain the original values for `N`, then you can first use `crossing` from `tidyr` to get all unique combinations. Then, we can do a left join to add in the `N` values from the original dataframe, and finally change `NA` to 0 for `N`.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(crossing(automatic = df$automatic, validated = df$validated), 
          df,
          by = c("automatic", "validated")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(N = 0))
```

Or a shorter option is to simply use `rows_update` instead of doing a join:

```
crossing(automatic = df$automatic, validated = df$validated, N = 0) %>% 
  rows_update(df, by = c("automatic", "validated"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 198 × 3
   automatic validated           N
   <chr>     <chr>           <int>
 1 bolha     appendicularia      0
 2 bolha     bolha               1
 3 bolha     cnidaria            0
 4 bolha     copepodo            0
 5 bolha     cosc_multiplo       0
 6 bolha     coscinodiscus       0
 7 bolha     detritos            0
 8 bolha     langanho            0
 9 bolha     mult_organismos     0
10 bolha     multiplos           0
# … with 188 more rows
```

Comment: Maybe I not explain right. Sorry. Where are combinations it has to maintain their value in `N` column. Like bolha (in `automatic` column) with bolha (in `validated` column) has a value in `N` of 1, it not have to change.

Comment: One thing that I note now. It continues not showing me the classes that have in `validated` in automatic. For example, has appendicularia in `validated`, are suppose it to be showed in `automatic`, but not are.

Comment: @WilsonSouza I am not following you. In you original dataframe, appendicularia is only in the validated column, so it wouldn't show up in the validated column. Unless, are you wanting the 2 columns reversed with the combos as well? So, put all the items in validated into automatic and all items in automatic into validated then have those combos as well? If that's the case, then in general when asking questions, I would do a smaller dataset, then give your expected output. It just helps us see exactly what you are wanting to get.

Comment: Thank @AndrewGB, It's exactly it what you did say.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `expand.grid` -> similar to @AndrewGB s solution:

```
library(dplyr)

expand_grid(automatic=df$automatic, validated=df$validated, N=0) %>% 
  rows_update(df, by = c("automatic", "validated")) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  arrange(automatic)

   automatic validated           N
   <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
 1 bolha     appendicularia      0
 2 bolha     bolha               1
 3 bolha     cnidaria            0
 4 bolha     copepodo            0
 5 bolha     cosc_multiplo       0
 6 bolha     coscinodiscus       0
 7 bolha     detritos            0
 8 bolha     langanho            0
 9 bolha     mult_organismos     0
10 bolha     multiplos           0
# … with 188 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `complete` which is a wrapper around expand and join

```
 df |> 
  complete(automatic, validated, fill = list(N = 0))
```

```
   automatic validated           N
   <chr>     <chr>           <int>
 1 bolha     appendicularia      0
 2 bolha     bolha               1
 3 bolha     cnidaria            0
 4 bolha     copepodo            0
 5 bolha     cosc_multiplo       0
 6 bolha     coscinodiscus       0
 7 bolha     detritos            0
 8 bolha     langanho            0
 9 bolha     mult_organismos     0
10 bolha     multiplos           0
# … with 188 more rows
```

If you want a unique combination whereby there is only one combination of automatic and validated when sorted. Then in dplyr  you can do

```
df |> 
       complete(automatic, validated, fill = list(N = 0)) |> 
       rowwise() |> 
       mutate(m = paste(sort(c(validated, automatic)), collapse = ", ")) |> 
       group_by(m) |> 
       filter(N == max(N)) |> 
       slice(1) |> 
       ungroup() |> 
       mutate(m = NULL)
```

```
# A tibble: 162 × 3
   automatic       validated          N
   <chr>           <chr>          <int>
 1 bolha           appendicularia     0
 2 coral_falso     appendicularia     0
 3 cosc_multiplo   appendicularia     0
 4 coscinodiscus   appendicularia     0
 5 detritos        appendicularia     0
 6 LRaw            appendicularia     0
 7 mult_organismos appendicularia     0
 8 multiplos       appendicularia     0
 9 org_partes      appendicularia     0
10 organismo       appendicularia     2
```